# How to customize react-md themes?

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I am using css-modules with react-md (https://react-md.mlaursen.com/) in my project.

I have included dark theme-
        @import '~react-md/src/scss/react-md';

```
$md-light-theme: false;
$md-primary-color: $md-light-blue-500;
$md-secondary-color: $md-deep-orange-a-200;

@include react-md-everything;
```

This applies the dark theme quite well on my web pages.
Now, my requirement is to be able to customize certain components like applying a background color to Card component, making all text certain color etc. How can this be done, please advise?